# Exercise of homogeneous function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

"Find all the class 2 functions $v=v(t)$ of the variable $t=x^2+y^2+z^2$ verifying the equation:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(f\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(f\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\left(f\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}\right)=0$$
where $f=f(x,y,z)$ is a differentiable, not identically zero and homogeneous of degree m function.

I have applied the product rule, then the chain rule for the composition of functions and in the end Euler theorem for homogeneous functions. Finally I have obtained the equation:

$m\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}+2\frac{\partial v^2}{\partial t^2}(x^2+y^2+z^2)=0$.

But the steps in which I have doubt are when I apply the chain rule. Would this be correct?:

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}2x$$.
Thanks for your help.